# Excel 2013 how can I default to Open in Backstage

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

In Excel 2013, my backstage defaults to Info.  How do I make it default to Open?  I don't want to bypass the backstage, I just want to go right to Open so I can see my Recent Workbooks that I use all the time.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried to add the `Open` command on the Quick Access toolbar?

Comment: Thank you.  I have done just that.  Now I just have to retrain my autopilot to go to the Quick Access toolbar instead of the File tab.